# How to use cpufreq

Tags: 16.04, cpufreq

I have watched a video about `cpufreq`, but its very outdated so, I want to know how can I use it now to save battery and set to power save or have full performance while charging.

Comment: It seems you want something like `lscpu` or `cat /proc/cpuinfo`, and [CPU Power Manager](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/945/cpu-power-manager/) extension to adjust the frequency.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt install indicator-cpufreq

reboot
```

if it crashes on boot try `sudo apt full-upgrade`

the app crashed on boot for me and reason was "you have some obsolete packaged versions installed. Please update"

Comment: Why would you do a full-upgrade if it crashes?

Comment: because am also trying to update it to 18.04, I assume anyone on 16.04 is wishing to do that, only a few months left until it's no longer supported

Comment: what does full upgrade do anyways is first time using it now the os wont start just stuck on loading screen

Comment: A full-upgrade is not the correct solution to crashes on a particular app

Comment: yeah I just realised 18.04 isn't supporting 32 bit so that's probably why the upgrading has fried the os so i'm trying now different ubuntu flavours

Comment: kubuntu 18.04.5 wins as it's 32 bit and is supported until 2021, gives another year of life to this machine